# Setting up variable to return function value or false

Tags: javascript

I wasn't sure how to properly word the title for this question but jumping right into it,

Using the the `? : operator` I setup a JavaScript variable and an if statement like so:

`var test = callsAFunction ? test : false;`

if I do this, will test equal whatever the function returns here? Or will it be undefined since it's "Technically" not set yet?

What I'm trying to do is set a variable to either what data it gets back and is run through a function, or set it to Boolean false so it will process through my Boolean check as an error.  I figured this approach was best but I'm running into issues determining how to go about this. Below are my code snippets:

```
var hash = self.getHashFromMasterRecords(d[0]);

if(hash === false){
                done("Can't find master record hash", self.requestData, self);
            }
```

Obviously it needs to turn false as a Boolean in order to pass as an error. I want to do this without having to call the function more than 1 time for this sequence.

So if I do `var hash = self.getHashFromMasterRecords(d[0]) ? hash : flase;` would hash return the value? Or undefined?

Thank you ahead of time, if I need to post more info let me know.

Comment: Have you tried it? Anyway `var hash = self.getHashFromMasterRecords(d[0]) || false;` is probably what you are looking for

Comment: That's what I was thinking of but couldn't get it past the tip of my tongue. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax:

```
var a = (b) ? c : d;
```

Will set `a` equal to `c` if `b` is evaluates to something truthy, and `d` if `b` evaluates to something falsy.  If I understand you correctly, you want to set a variable to the return value of a function, and if that function fails, set it to some default value.  To do that, use `||`:

```
var a = b() || 'error occurred!';
```

In the line above, if `b()` evaluates to something falsy, `a` will get the value of `error occurred!`.  If `b()` evaluates to something truthy, it will get the return value of `b()`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification I was thinking along those lines but could not get it fully on of the tip of my tongue.

Answer (score 1):

It would be undefined.  As long as your function returns a falsey value when it returns you can use the or (`||`) operator:

```
var hash = self.getHashFromMasterRecords(d[0]) ?? false;
```

Although, if that is a concrete example there is little value in the above code as you'd already have a falsey value by just storing the result from the function.